# Square of a Sequence of Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, exponentiation

This is a simple question, but I could not find the solution.

What is the compact form of expansion of $(n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k)^2$

Is it: $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}n_in_j$

Is there any reference?

Comment: I think $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n n_i)^2$ is more compact.

Comment: You can also write $(\sum_1^nx_i)^2=\sum_1^nx_i^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_ix_j $. It is acceptable to write only one "$\sum$" symbol in the last summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using distributivity and commutativity we have
\begin{align*}
 \left( \sum_{i=1}^k n_i \right)^2
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^k n_i \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{j=1}^k n_j \right)
= \sum_{i=1}^k  \left(n_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^k n_j   \right)
= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k  \left(n_i \cdot n_j   \right) \\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^k n_i n_j
= \sum_{1 \leq i = j \leq k} n_i n_j + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} n_i n_j
   + \sum_{1 \leq j < i \leq k} n_i n_j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} n_i n_j
   + \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} \underbrace{n_j n_i}_{= n_i n_j}
= \sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} n_i n_j \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^k n_i n_j.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

It is right in a commutative ring.

Just compute it like this way:
$(n_1+n_2+...)(n_1+n_2+...)=\Sigma_{i=j}n_i n_j+\Sigma_{i<j}n_i n_j+\Sigma_{i>j}n_i n_j=\Sigma_{i=j}n_i n_j+2\Sigma_{i<j}n_i n_j$

Comment: Haha, I don't think OP knows what that is.

Comment: I don't know commutative ring, but got the point. Thanks!